# Seeking information about medical and financial issues

Tags: estate-planning, long-term-disability

I have an elderly cousin who lives far from me who I assist with some of her financial affairs.  She is a widow, has no children, nor does she have any relatives or trusted friends locally who can step in the event of disabilititating injury/illness.

She is about to apply for long term care benefits.  I've looked at the claim application and it is a bit daunting.  I'm wondering if other than her physician, is there any other professional that can be consulted regarding how to best fill out the application?  In addition, she is contemplating making the Trust Department of a local bank the executor of her Trust.

I'd appreciate any feedback regarding the best way to approach these issues.  TIA.

Comment: A lawyer specializing in elder law. They do wills but a lot more.

Answer (score 2):

The local services available for elders may include free consultation on this kind of issue; if not they may be able to suggest good affordable resources in her area. I'd start by making some phone calls to them, checking both secular and religiously affiliated groupes even though I myself am agnostic. There may also be advice/forms available from national organizations on their websites; I know Compassion And Choices has a lot of end-of-life resources though they focus mostly on medical proxies and "living wills".

If you can't find something free or discounted, then New Name's suggestion if a lawyer who specializes in elder care strikes me as worth checking; at the very least they can give more recommendations.